# PHP form sends but "No Sender"

Tags: php, forms, email

I am able to receive email with all the information except for the email address that is entered in the form, and when I receive the email, I get "No Sender" instead of the person's name or email.

This is my HTML:

```
        <!-- Contact Form -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
            <div id="contant-form-bx" class="contant-form-bx">
                <div class="contact-loader"></div>
                <form action="mail.php" id="contact-form" class="contact-form" name="cform" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">  
                            <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
                            <span class="name-missing">Please enter your name!</span>  
                            <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name" size="30"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-md-6 columns"> 
                            <label for="e-mail" id="email_label">Email</label>
                            <span class="email-missing">Please enter a valid e-mail!</span> 
                            <input id="e-mail" type="text" value="" name="email" size="30">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"> 
                            <label for="message" id="phone_label">Message</label>
                            <span class="message-missing">Say something!</span>
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message">  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my PHP:

```
    <?php
// declare our variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['e-mail'];
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);

// set a title for the message
$subject = "From $name via WEB";
$body = "From $name, \n\n$message";
$headers = 'From: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// put your email address here
mail("info@wziel.com", $subject, $body, $headers);
?>

<!--Display a Thank you message in the callback -->
<div class="mail_response">
    <h4>Thank you <?php echo $name ?>!</h4>
    <p>I'll be in touch real soon!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Going by the answer, you could have figured this out by just enabling `error_reporting` → given that something doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$_POST['e-mail']`. `e-mail` is the ID of the `<input>` tag. You should be using `$_POST['email']` because `name="email"`.

Comment: i change this but now the email take forever to be delivered ! 

any help ?

Comment: @WzielPaniagua This change shouldn't impact the length of time it takes to deliver an email in any significant way. It's more likely your email server is just lagging.

Comment: weird when i change it back to e-mail work instantly

Comment: Define "forever". It can't be taking _that_ long because you hadn't even tried it until 23 minutes ago...

Comment: i did it  23 minutes ago nothing in the inbox yet. when i change it back to "e-mail" got it immediately –

Comment: @WzielPaniagua Check your spam box.

Answer (score 3):

According to your form this:

```
$email = $_POST['e-mail'];
```

Should be this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

You have `e-mail` as the `id` not the `name`.

The php looks at `name` and not `id`

Comment: but the input id is 

`<input id="e-mail" type="text" value="" name="email" size="30">` 

?

Comment: id will not be passed to php, it is for client side tasks only (javascript, css, etc.) when the form submits the only thing that gets passed is the value of `name` and the actual value of the field.